# Python - Maior valor de um dicionário por chave

Tags: python-3.x

Bom dia a todos.

Preciso de uma grande ajuda com um projeto que estou fazendo. Estou com dificuldades em pegar somente os maiores valores de um dicionário ou de uma lista.
Vou tentar explicar melhor:

Na linguagem AWK eu faria assim para os maiores valores:

```
if (FILENAME == "..\\temp\\empregados.txt") {
    emp = substr($1, 1, 3)+0;
    i_emp = substr($1, 5)+0;

    if (i_emp > maior[emp])
        maior[emp] = i_emp

    print $0 > "..\\dados\\empregados.txt"
```

Aqui "if (i_emp > maior[emp])" está o pulo do gato, pois eu crio um arrey chamado "maior e passo como posição desse arrey o emp. Com isso ele vai me dizer das empresas que tenho cadastrado, qual o código do maior empregado por empresa.

Ainda não vi como trabalhar com arreys desse tipo no Python para eu poder pegar qual o maior código de cada empresa.

Ex:
Tenho o arquivo csv separado por "tab" asssim:

codigo_empresa codigo_empregado
2 2-201
2 2-200
2 2-305
2 2-002
3 3-305
3 3-405
3 3-105

E por ai vai.
Preciso que ele guarde os seguintes valores:
2 2-305
3 3-405

Desde já agradeço a todos pela posterior ajuda.

Comment: Perguntas são para... bem, perguntas. Se quer responder a sua própria pergunta, [publique uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422/5878). Só tome cuidado para não responder apenas com o código que está funcionando; junto com o código poste a explicação do que estava errado e como resolveu.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento Anderson Carlos Woss.
Sou novo por aqui, então ainda não estou habituado com o funcionamento, mas vou me ajustando.. Grato.

Comment: Veja esse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/475306/como-acessar-a-chave-pelo-valor-em-dicion%c3%a1rio-python/475330#475330)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse foi o jeito que encontrei para resolver esse meu problema:

```
for row in read_file:
    codi = dict(row).get("CODI")
    codigo_empresa = codi[:3]
    codigo_empregado = codi[4:8]

   if codigo_empresa not in dict_empregado_maior:
       dict_empregado_maior[codigo_empresa] = codigo_empregado
   elif codigo_empregado > dict_empregado_maior[codigo_empresa]:
       dict_empregado_maior[codigo_empresa] = codigo_empregado
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia você pode usar a função MAX do Python .

```
dic = {'A': 58, 'B': 100, 'C': 42, 'D': 99, 'E': 12}
dic[max(dic, key=dic.get)]
```

Saída:

```
100
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Johnatan Dantas, mas assim também irá me trazer somente o maior valor geral do dicionário e não o maior valor de cada chave.

Já consegui fazer o que eu queria e vou postar aqui.

Grato

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `sorted` com o parâmetro `reverse=True` se quiser uma lista em ordem decrescente.

```
lista = 1.2, 2.8, 3.9, 4.1, 5.8

print(sorted(lista, reverse=True))
```

Saída:

```
[5.8, 4.1, 3.9, 2.8, 1.2]
```

Comment: Bom dia Éder Garcia.
Essa até seria a solução se eu tivesse querendo ordenar somente, mas estou querendo deixar somente os códigos maiores de cada empresa.

Estou estudando uma solução com dicionários, se der certo posto aqui o resultado.

Comment: Boa sorte Cleber. Aguardando para ver a solução!

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem. você tem um dicionario do tipo abaixo:

```
empr = {2:[201,200,305,2],
        3:[305,405,105]
        }
```

Logo uma forma de solucionar isso é a seguinte:

```
selec = {}

for key in empr.keys(): # não precisa do .keys() mas fica mais intuitivo
    selec[key] = max(empr[key])


print(selec)

{2: 305, 3: 405}
```

Bata iterar pela chave o dic gerado pela tabela e pegar o valor máximo.

Comment: Valeu Júlio, esse é um jeito melhor de escrever o que eu fiz lá em cima. Grato.