# Como acessar a chave, pelo valor, em dicionário python?

Tags: python, dicionário

Ao preencher o nome de 10 pessoas e suas respectivas alturas, preciso mostrar na tela o nome da pessoa mais alta. No entanto, só consigo pegar o maior valor.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
people = {}
count = 1
while count <= 2:
    name = str(input('Name: ').strip().title())
    while True:
        try:
            people[name] = float(input('Height: '))
            if type(people[name]) == float:
               break
        except ValueError:
            print('Numbers. Try again.')
    count += 1

print(people)
```

Comment: Fazendo uma busca no Stack Overflow encontrei uma pergunta que possui a resposta para o que precisa, segue link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382490/python-maior-valor-de-um-dicion%C3%A1rio-por-chave

Comment: Só um detalhe, ao fazer `float(input(...))`, o resultado já é um `float`, então não precisa verificar se o `type` da variável é `float`. Se não for digitado um número válido, ele lança o `ValueError` e o código cai direto no `except`, então esse `if` é desnecessário, vc poderia chamar o `break` direto: https://ideone.com/7Ah4Ap

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja implementar um script que seja capaz de montar um `dicionário` contendo `nome` e `altura` de 10 pessoas e, em seguida, exiba o nome da pessoa mais alta.

Pois bem, você pode utilizar o seguinte script:

```
# Montando um dicionário com nome e altura de 10 pessoas.
people = dict()
for c in range(1, 11):
    n = input(f'{c}º Nome: ').strip().title()
    a = float(input(f'Altura de {n}: '))
    people.update({n: a})

# Verificando a maior altura.
maior = people[max(people, key=people.get)]
print('\033[32mPessoa(s) de maior(es) altura(s):')
for n, a in people.items():
    if a == maior:
        print(f'{n}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este script é executado o **1º bloco for**. É por intermédio dele que será montado o respectivo dicionário.

Então, quando executamos o script recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `1º Nome:` . Neste momento devemos digitar o primeiro nome e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida, recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Altura de fulano:` . Neste momento devemos digitar a altura do referido fulano e pressionar `enter`. Em seguida devemos digitar o nome e altura das demais pessoas.

Depois de digitar nome e altura da última pessoa - 10ª pessoa - e pressionarmos `enter`, será executado o **2º bloco for**. Neste momento, será verificada a maior altura e o(s) nome(s) da(s) pessoa(s) que a possui. Em seguida é exibido o(s) nome(s) da(s) pessoa(s) de maior altura.

**Observação**

**A FUNÇÃO PRIORITÁRIA DE UM LAÇO DE REPETIÇÃO - NO CASO AQUI UM FOR - É JUSTAMENTE REPETIR INTERAÇÕES**. Pois bem, se não tivesse inserido o **2º** **FOR** só seria exibido uma só pessoa que, porventura, tivesse a maior altura. Como inserir o **2º FOR** o código será capaz de exibir **O NOME DE TODAS AS PESSOAS** que, porventura, tiverem a altura máxima.

Então, a utilização deste **2º FOR** e **ALTAMENTE NECESSÁRIO**.

Pois se você prestar atenção o **penúltimo print()**...

```
print('\033[32mPessoa(s) de maior(es) altura(s):')
```

...faz referência aos casos de se ter apenas uma saída - um só nome de pessoa - ou a mais saídas - várias pessoas.

Comment: Entendi. Muito Obrigada!

Comment: Você deu uma volta na sua resposta - o `max` com Kye já ocnsegue o nome da maior pessoa, e aí é só usar o dicionário - é completamente desnecessário o  `for` final.: nome_maiior = max(people, key=people.get); maior_altura = people[nome_maior] `

Comment: @jsbueno Acho que o `for` no final é interessante se tiver empate (mais de uma pessoa com altura igual à maior)

Comment: @hkotsubo  - ok, para um feature a mais de "qual a maior altura" - mas isso passa por cima e não responde "como acessar a chave pelo valor" (que é a pergunta) - o melhor seria explicar "aqui é a chave - mas como podem haver repetições do valor, fazemos mais isso ... "

Comment: @Solkarped  -  legal você querer mostrar o texto colorido com a ANSI sequence - mas tem duas coisas legais pra voce ter em mente: (1) não é muito legível ou mantivel ter sequências loucas de caracteres em cada print - você pode por a sequencia pra mudar de cor em uma variável e aí usar prints do tipo  `print(f"{VERMELHO} Pessoa(s) de maior(es) altura(s): {NORMAL} )"` . Outra coisa: essas sequências não funcionam no Windows por padrão, então é legal mencionar isso.

Comment: @jsbueno Concordo, faltou colocar uma explicação desse `for`...

Comment: @hkotsubo, expus de forma detalhada o `uso` do `2º for`. Outra coisa, como `uma pessoa` é um subconjunto de `várias pessoa`, então a minha resposta é suficiente para responder a esta pergunta.

Comment: @jsbueno, quanto a `coloração` da resposta, vou aceitar seu parecer.

Answer (score 3):

Aqui vai uma outra solução que lida com a situação em que há duas pessoas de altura máxima no dicionário:

```
pessoas = {
    "João": 1.71, 
    "Maria": 1.69,
    "Alberto": 1.75,
    "Joana": 1.70, 
    "Pedro": 1.75
}

mais_altas = [pessoa for pessoa, altura in pessoas.items() if 
              altura == max(pessoas.values())]
```

`mais_altas` é uma lista de todos os nomes das pessoas cuja altura é a maior altura no dicionário `pessoas`.

A sintaxe usada na última linha é chamada de compreensão de lista, que é uma forma mais simples de escrever um for loop. Aqui é a versão equivalente do mesmo for loop, "por extenso":

```
mais_altas = []
maior_altura = max(pessoas.values())  # encontra maior altura nos valores
for pessoa, altura in pessoas.items():  # itera sobre pares chave-valor
    if altura == maior_altura:  # quando a altura da pessoa for a maior / uma das maiores:
        mais_altas.append(pessoa)
```

Comment: Simples demais! Obrigada por ajudar! Inclusive, entrei hoje na list comprehensions, já foi ótimo aprender um pouco sobre a aula hoje, com essa resposta.

Comment: Ótimo, que bom que consegui ajudar :-)

Answer (score 1):

Você poder fazer igual [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/382574/18327) ([mencionada no comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/475306/como-acessar-a-chave-pelo-valor-em-dicion%C3%A1rio-python#comment892649_475306)):

```
print(max(people, key=people.get))
```

ou se preferir, percorrer direto as chaves do dicionário e ir comparando seus valores:

```
names = list(people.keys())
if len(names) > 0:
  # inicia o primeiro nome como sendo o maior
  taller = names[0]

  # percorre todos os nomes a partir do segundo
  for name in names[1:]:
    if people.get(name, 0) > people.get(taller, 0):
      taller = name

  print(taller)
else:
  print('no one')
```

Comment: Muito obrigada!